# how to force onLayout

Tags: android, view

Hi i want to design a custom View where I need to recalculate my layout and redraw when user changes something.
To force a `onLayout()`, the only solution that works for me until now is:

```
onLayout(true, 0, 0, 0, 0);
invalidate();
```

Of course that gives me a lint error and I have to add a `@SuppressLint("WrongCall")`.

So there must be a smarter solution.
Calls of forceLayout or requestLayout didn't work.
Probably they only put a request on a stack but don't react immediately.

As my view has no child elements and I do the drawing inside all by myself,
could be I'm bypassing some Android design guides and abusing some principles.

Can live with the lint error but maybe someone already found a solution.
Thanks!